# How to pass a variable value in awk NR

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass a variable value in awk NR function to count all files from a file after a string / text.

```
awk '/mystring/ {s=NR;next} s' myfile|wc -l
25
```

Below code fails.

```
 lastFile="mystring"
awk -v var="$lastFile" '/var/ {s=NR;next} s' myfile|wc -l
0
```

The expected output is 25, but i am getting 0.

-Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it like this with `~` operator to get a regex match:

```
awk -v var="$lastFile" '$0 ~ var {s=NR;next} s' myfile | wc -l
```

Here you have to make sure that `$var` doesn't contain any special regex characters.

Better to not to use `regex` and perform plain string search using `index`:

```
awk -v var="$lastFile" 'index($0, var) {s=NR;next} s' myfile | wc -l
```